Can a bathroom fan vent be tied into the sewer exhaust?
House is still under builders warranty, I have informed the builder of this and several hazard concerns that were found but as of yet unresponsive. The fan is tied into where the sewer exhaust is ran out the exterior. I am going to the verify with the local codes to see what options I have if the builder does not respond.


I didn't really know how to word it, it wouldn't let me upload a photo from my phone. I am a little disgruntled with the builder, the lack of communication over the past 11 months has been  very frustrating, hence why I went a head an paid for an inspection and I am glad I did. Electrical problems have been found but the exhaust fan seemed priority to the inspector. I am verifying codes before I look at other options if the builder continues to be unresponsive

"tied" has too many different possible meanings, I can't guess ehat you actually have.

The bathroom exhaust fan tubing is directly connected into the sewer vent and is held on with what looks like duct tape. I will see if I can add a link to view photo.

https://www.imghippo.com/i/wUo741722484462.jpg

@user231140, Image added -- to add an image, 1. Edit the question. 2. Click the button with a tiny "scenic mountain" icon, above the edit box, to insert the pic. 3. Also, I hate to imagine a backup in that vent -- it puts new meaning to "the s--t hit the fan". [Though this might be code compliant. - IDK]

Duct tape? they should have used a reducer,   it would still be extremely wrong.  I'm pretty sure code says it needs a trap before it can connect to the vent stack.

I'm no expert in ventilation, but I don't think that fan is going to vent much. Bathroom fans create very low static pressure - all the pipework is going to create a lot of back-pressure.

@Jasen how do you "trap" airflow?  Are you talking about a vent flap or something?

@Huesmann you can't  this setup is cursed.

@Jasen you said "pretty sure code says it needs a trap" and I'm asking how you put in a trap for a tube that carries air, not water.

A trap is needed for a connection to the drain and vent piping.  there's no sensible way to put a trap in a vent duct.   maybe some sort of backflow preventer could be used (I have not searched in the code).  but even then the reduction in diameter is prbably forbidden by some other regulation. also the tee is installed upside down.  It's cursed. Irredeemable. Do-over.

It was difficult to understand what you were telling us, then the picture tells the story. I have never encountered a bath fan tied into a plumbing vent.
I'm guessing that the workers ran the duct and found the roofers forgot to put in a vent to tie into. So they "improvised" !
That is wrong on so many levels. The worst thing is, it tells of lack of pride in workmanship.
If the builder will not respond, take the pic and your contract and if you have a copy of the permit to the local building authorities. There is the question of how that passed inspection as well.

Yeah, I'd write this up as an IPC 903.4 violation myself, and this could also create excessive positive pressure in the vent stack (which'd break trap seals).  Never mind that it creates a path for sewer gasses to leak into the house!

I appreciate the responses. It's just been very frustrating with this builder and I am not sure of the exact terms that needed to be used so apologies if it caused any confusion.  Again I appreciate the responses.
